# mysql - For the row which column contains a string, get the string from the other column

Tags: mysql

```
    mysql> select * from newschema.users where username = 'test';
    +----------+----------+
    | username | password |
    +----------+----------+
    | test     | lolol    |
    +----------+----------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So a username named 'test' exists. Now how do I get the "lolol" value from the password column?

(Sorry if my english is bad, I don't know how to phrase it properly)

Comment: try with a simple tutorial about sql select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty straight forward usecase for a `select` statement - you specify one column in the select list and use the other in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT password
FROM   newschema.users
WHERE  username = 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select password from newschema.users where username = 'test';
```

Try this. It selects the password column.